# Puppeteer not working as excepted (pause/freeze when browser not in focus)

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, chromium, freeze

I'm using Puppeteer.js to crawl some URL. I'm using the default Chromium browser of Puppeteer.
All is working well, but the problem is, that when I run the crawling script, and doing other things in the background and the focus is no longer on the Chromium browser of Puppeteer, it's not working: waiting for elements way too long, and abort operations, or in other words: puppeteer is paused (or freeze).

P.S, I'm also using [puppeteer-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra) and [puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth) NPM packages for advance options.

Here is how I create the browser and the page:

```
async initiateCrawl(isDisableAsserts) {
    // Set the browser.
    this.isPlannedClose = false;
    const browser = await puppeteerExtra.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: [
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
            '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
            '--start-maximized',
            '--disable-background-timer-throttling',
            '--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows',
            '--disable-renderer-backgrounding'
        ]
    });
    const pid = browser.process().pid;
    browser.on('disconnected', () => {
        systemUtils.killProcess(pid);
        if (!this.isPlannedClose) {
            systemUtils.exit(Status.BROWSER_CLOSE, Color.RED, 0);
        }
    });
    process.on('SIGINT', () => {
        this.close(browser, true);
    });
    // Set the page and close the first empty tab.
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const pages = await browser.pages();
    if (pages.length > 1) {
        await pages[0].close();
    }
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(this.timeout);
    page.on('request', (request) => {
        if (isDisableAsserts && ['image', 'stylesheet', 'font', 'script'].indexOf(request.resourceType()) !== -1) {
            request.abort();
        } else {
            request.continue();
        }
    });
    return {
        browser: browser,
        page: page
    };
}
```

I already looked at: 
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3339 
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-launcher/issues/169 
https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/3339/530620329

Not working solutions:

```
const session = await page.target().createCDPSession();
await session.send('Page.enable');
await session.send('Page.setWebLifecycleState', {state: 'active'});
```

- 

```
const chromeArgs = [
  '--disable-background-timer-throttling',
  '--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows',
  '--disable-renderer-backgrounding'
];
```

- 

```
var ops = {args:[
        '--kiosks',
        '--disable-background-timer-throttling',
        '--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows',
        '--disable-renderer-backgrounding',
        '--disable-canvas-aa',
        '--disable-2d-canvas-clip-aa',
        '--disable-gl-drawing-for-tests',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage', 
        '--no-zygote', 
        '--use-gl=desktop', 
        '--enable-webgl',
        '--hide-scrollbars',
        '--mute-audio',
        '--start-maximized',
        '--no-first-run',
        '--disable-infobars',
        '--disable-breakpad', 
        '--user-data-dir='+tempFolder, 
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
    ], headless: false, timeout:0   };
puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    browser = await puppeteer.launch(ops);
    page = await browser.newPage();
```

Has anyone faced this issue before and have any idea how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, it was working fine, but recently it has stopped working.

Comment: is there any error thrown after some amount of time is elapsed?

Comment: @Mu-Majid no, the browser just freeze.

Comment: Maybe running in headless mode solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was solved when I updated to the latest puppeteer version (9.0.0).